# How to install "org.Hs.eg.db" package in R v3.5.1?

Tags: r, version, bioconductor, install.packages

I've just installed the latest R version 3.5.1, and tried to install the "org.Hs.eg.db" package. But I receive this error when I ran the code:

```
> install.packages("org.Hs.eg.db")
Installing package into 'C:/Users/ashley/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'org.Hs.eg.db' is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this?

I was able to install the "org.Hs.eg.db" package in older R version 3.5.0.

Thank you very much.

Ashley.

Comment: Have you tried these [installation instructions](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.Hs.eg.db.html)?

Comment: @juzraai: Thank you. I tried the installation and it work.

Comment: You're welcome! :) I added it as answer with some additional information.

Answer (score 3):

`org.Hs.eg.db` is a Bioconductor package, and from the error message, it seems that this package is not included in the default repository where R searches.

Bioconductor's [install guide](https://bioconductor.org/install/) says you should use the script they provide to install packages:

> Use the `biocLite.R` script to install Bioconductor packages.

And the package's [install guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.Hs.eg.db.html) lists the exact commands you need to install `org.Hs.eg.db` package:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("org.Hs.eg.db")
```

Comment: `BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")` works as well

Answer (score 0):

You may use below instruction:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")
```

Base on [this](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.Hs.eg.db.html) link

Answer (score 0):

**Problem: I have faced similar error**

> install.packages("org.Mm.eg.db")
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘org.Mm.eg.db’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

**Solution:**

> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))

- ```
  install.packages("BiocManager")
  ```

> BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")

Comment: You could format the answer better (anything coming out of a console or ide should be formatted as code), but aside from that, thanks for sharing your experience.